# How to return the most common items in a list that are closely related in value in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

Suppose I have a list:

```
lst = [2.2, 2.23, 2.24, 3, 4, 5, 3.8]
```

I would like to know if there is a function out there that figures out that my most common and related numbers are:

```
most_common = [2.2, 2.23, 2.24]
```

From there i can return the smallest of the list or do whatever other operation i want.

This is the function i am using so far and i am not pleased with the results

```
max(set(lst), key=lst.count)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How exactly do you define "closely related"? Without a precise definition, there is no way to solve this.

Comment: You would need to tell such a function just what "most common and related numbers" means. What do you mean? Do you mean close in absolute or relative terms? How close is close enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by most common. You can use this algorithm and set precision with `eps` variable:

```
a = [2.2, 2.23, 2.24, 3, 4, 5, 3.8]
eps = 0.5


def find_relative(values, eps):
    minimum, maximum = 0, 0
    result = []
    temp = []
    for v in sorted(values):
        if not temp:
            minimum = maximum = v
            temp.append(v)
        else:
            if abs(v - minimum) < eps and abs(v - maximum) < eps:
                temp.append(v)
                if v < minimum:
                    minimum = v
                elif v > maximum:
                    maximum = v
            else:
                if len(temp) > 1:
                    result.append(temp)
                minimum = maximum = v
                temp = [v]
    return result


print(find_relative(a, eps))  # [[2.2, 2.23, 2.24], [3.8, 4]]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I had something similar in mind but didn't know where to start or if i should mention it lest i ruin the answers.

Comment: My other approach was to go nuclear on the items in the list,  convert them to strings, find values at each index and use some scoring mechanism to find my closely related numbers. What do you thing about that?

Comment: @Edwinner, I am not sure how it is possible to give score to a number. The score of a number would be a number itself. The only question there is is how close do the numbers need to be to be neighbors , that's why we need to have something like epsilon here.

Comment: i meant if two values at a given same index are equal, i give it say a score of 100% and so on. I was trying to stay away from specifying a hard-coded epsilon. But still, if all fails, your answer is the best i have so far.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [2.2, 2.23, 2.24, 3, 4, 5, 3.8]
a_round = []
a_1 = []

for item in a:
    a_round.append(round(item,1))

for ir in range(0, len(a_round)):
    if a_round.count(a_round[ir]) > 1:
        a_1.append(a[ir])

print(a_1)
```

ans : [2.2, 2.23, 2.24]

Comment: Great answer! I am gonna try it with a couple of my values.